# Why am I getting "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an error in Swift that I don't understand. Here is the code from my playground:

```
class Person : CustomStringConvertible
{

    let Name :String;
    let DoB :NSDate?

    init(name :String, dob :NSDate?)
    {
        Name = name;
        DoB = dob;
    }

    func age() -> Double {
        let now = NSDate();
        let age :Double = now.timeIntervalSinceDate(self.DoB!);

        return age;
    }

    var description : String {
        return "Name: \(Name), Age: \(self.age())";
    }

}

extension NSDate {
    static func dateFromComponents(year :Int, month :Int, day :Int) -> NSDate {
        let components = NSDateComponents();
        components.year = year;
        components.month = month;
        components.day = day;
        return components.date!;
    }
}

let helena = Person(name: "Helena", dob: NSDate.dateFromComponents(1986, month: 8, day: 10));
print(helena);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for the NSDateComponents `date` property:

> Returns `nil` if the `calendar` property value of the receiver is `nil` or cannot convert the receiver into an NSDate object.

You have not set the date components' `calendar`, so `.date` is nil. Read [the answers on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32170456/23649) for more about unwrapping optionals.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that

```
NSDate.dateFromComponents(1986, month: 8, day: 10)
```

returns nil.

You can solve that by creating a date object like this:

```
let format = NSDateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = format.dateFromString("1986-08-10")!
```

and then pass it like this:

```
let helena = Person(name: "Helena", dob: date);
print(helena);
```

#### Using NSCalender

```
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.year = 2000
components.month = 8
components.day = 1
let calender = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:  NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)
let date2 = calender!.dateFromComponents(components)

let helena2 = Person(name: "Helena", dob: date2);
```

Comment: NSDateComponents is a perfectly valid approach (cleaner than using a string), it just isn't being used properly.

Comment: @jtbandes totally agree ... updated using NSCalender

Comment: OK, but are you still recommending that OP should use a string? Your answer doesn't explain why using NSCalendar is important.

Comment: @jtbandes no , the components are numbers

Comment: @jtbandes the question is not about NSDate, it is about the nil exception. that'd be a different question

Comment: The simplest solution in this case is to set the `calendar` property of `components` in the class method: `components.calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()`